# Is my application loading a dll to use std::string?

Tags: c++, windows, dll, static-libraries

I'm working on an application that needs to be compatible up to Windows XP (yea... I know...), my colleagues are arguing that they don't want to use `std::string` because it *might* load some `dlls` that *might* change the code behavior.

I'm not sure either if they are right or wrong here. At some point, there **has** to be some common grounds where the application can be loaded.

And so given the context where an application have to be self contained as much as possible, would this application be required to load a `dll` in order to use the `stl` or `string` or else coming from the standard libraries?

Also, assuming I use the `-static-libstdc++` flag, by which order of magnitude will the executable be bigger?

Comment: No. Your colleagues are only correct if you don't use static linking. This will happen for ALL stl containers and functions. `std::vector`, `std::string`, etc.. It'd have to load `libgcc_s_sjlj-1` and `libstdc++-6`. However if you compile with `-static`, `-static-libgcc`, `-static-libstdc++` then it will not need to load anything. The code will be statically linked into your executable and fully contained. Executable will be larger though. The above is for gcc/g++/mingw. If using MSVC, then it loads `msvcrtXX.dll` where XX is a version number. Not sure if `msvcrt` is related to stl though..

Comment: @Brandon Larger in what order of magnitude?

Comment: A lot larger. I can't give exact numbers because it's different for everyone. You will actually be statically compiling everything with the above flags and not just stl code alone but Windows code too (`gdi`, `comctrl`, etc). For that reason it'd be quite a bit larger. I'm not sure of any way to only statically link gcc. Perhaps adding only the gcc libs to the linker and removing the static flag(s) `could` work; but I'm not `100%` sure of that.

Answer (score 0):

In windows, STL is supported using CRT libraries. These libraries require the run time DLLs to be deployed before you running the application. Compiling code with different version of visual studio will create dependency on a particular version of CRT. Compiling code with vs2013 will need a version of CRT much different than the vs2010. So you cannot use/pass STL objects from one version of CRT to another dll consuming a different version. Please go through microsoft articles before consuming the CRT libraries. Below article is for vs2013:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh.aspx
I would suggest you to use ATL:CString which is much easier to implement & the static version library also much compact than CRT libraries.

Comment: Assuming I always build the application against the XP CRT (Platform Toolset in MSVC if I'm right), then should I worry about compatibility between, say XP and Windows 7/8?

Comment: If all the components use the same CRT then your good to use it. It should work across all OS.